# Error while making a SENT using Derma GUI in Gmod

Tags: user-interface, null, lua

I am making a SENT in Gmod with Lua and I want it to have a simple GUI menu using Derma. I have put the following into my cl_init.lua file:

```
local plantwinow = vgui.Create("DFrame")
plantwinow:SetSize(202, 102)
plantwinow:Center()
plantwinow:SetTitle("Level " +lvltext +" Plant")
plantwinow:SetDraggable(true)
plantwinow:SetSizable(false)
plantwinow:ShowCloseButton(true)
plantwinow:MakePopup()
```

This gives me the error

```
prog.lua:1: attempt to index global 'vgui' (a nil value)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is the compilers way of telling you that `vgui` isn't defined. Please describe what you've done to define `vgui` or at least how you're running this script since this error would be expected from an unmodified Lua install.

Comment: I fixed this problem myself; an addon was causing it to be undefined where Gmod would normally define it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to register your file using includes and AddCSLuafile it, here is how it works:
shared.lua:

```
if SERVER then
      AddCSLuaFile("cl_init.lua")
else
      include("cl_init.lua")
end
```

If your addon / entity has init.lua then please tell me your init.lua.